# Raspbian as OS of a controller module of a machine

Tags: gpl, operating-system

I'd like to use a Raspberry Pi as a controller of a rather complex medical machine. For several reasons, most prominently safety reasons, it is out of the question, that we could give the source code to anyone (the machine can kill patients).

Could we still install [Raspbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian) together with our software and then sell the machine like that?

I thought it must be possible, but I can't find any definitive answer.

Comment: (1) In the long run, peer review is generally considered to be safer than security through obscurity. If you don’t publish your code, then the only people who know its weaknesses / vulnerabilities will be the hackers who have decompiled it. (2) What are you asking, exactly? Whether the market will buy a product with potentially lethal capabilities with unpublished / unreviewed code? Whether your legal liability is decreased or increased by your attempt to keep the inner workings secret? How hard it is to decompile embedded software in a hardware product?  Most of these questions are off-topic.

Comment: The question is largely off-topic here. The answer is probably you can, wether you want to use that hw is another kettle of fishes. IANAL. get a lawyer.

Comment: @Rui Thanks, btw. my lawyer is looking into the question, but i'm just a bit impatiant...

Comment: @G-Man (1) It's not only about safety. The features within the controler are a major advantage over our competition and years of research went into that... (2) The market will buy it. It's only about GPL-compliance (3) If this question is off-topic here, where should it go?

Comment: [This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/125606) would be relevant to this.

Comment: I don’t believe you could use a stock pi. Medical devices require proprietary connectors, charger, etc. At least in the US. The Pi has standard usb, Ethernet, and barrel jack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPL is claimed usually on a per file basis as it relates to a program. This license disclaimer usually looks something like:

"The following program is under the GPL" or "This file is licensed under the GPL" or "The code in the directory myprogram is licenced under the GPL except for icon.png which is license on CC-BY-SA. You can find these licenses in the file COPYING"

Further GPLs copyleft nature applies to derivative works of what was claimed in the disclaimer which at least so far in the copyright world hasn't meant things that run or use the program. The GPL does claim that linking a program creates a derivative work that includes both the program the linked libraries.

Further source code and compiled programs in itself doesn't constitute a derivative work just because its sitting on a file system with other works no more than putting a painting on your wall makes a derivative work if its placed next to another painting.

So while the software is GPLed USING the software as part of a system doesn't invoke copyleft. Only the act of combining code together to make a greater program does (add source code to the file or link code together when compiling to make a single program etc.)

I would assume open source helps you make sure your system is secure and free of most bugs. You can use GPL internal to an organization but if you're selling you have to provide the source code publicly.

The concept where you agree to a contract or license as part of your USE of a program is called an End User License Agreement (EULA). Free software is the diametric opposite of this as it grants users of that software the rights to use for any purpose. Further EULAs aren't necessarily invoked by copyright and are usually instead enforced by "click-wrap."

When you distribute GPLed software however you have obligations to provide the sourcecode of THAT software. That wasn't asked in your question but it dawns on me you might miss that.

Comment: I'm assuming you could in theory make the claim that say all parts of a system are "part" of the same work and this could have weird effects. Although thats not the case anyway. Still installing your own software doesn't matter here you could still do that without a problem because USING software doesn't invoke copyright even if that software is combining functionality together (like what happens with interprocess communication).

Answer (score 1):

Your taking a hardware device and pre-installing an OS and then your software before selling it as a final package. Provided you comply with the terms of each software package you install, by providing access to the source code as needed and the licensing of your program doesn't conflict with other licenses you should be good.

Commercial programs can be installed onto linux systems without having to be open sourced but some software may not be *distributed* with open source software. For legal reasons you may need to distinguish between the tasks you perform, eg. the invoice will be for the purchase of the hardware, a copy of your software, plus a setup fee for you installing the software and configuring the machine for the customer.

Choosing whether to open source your program is a different issue, it isn't your software (ignoring bugs here) or access to it's source code that can harm a patient, it is the user, anyone can pull the power cord or press buttons to harm a patient, that is a different issue than accessing the code for the software controlling the machine.

Comment: In (certified) medical software/devices, the manufacturer has an obligation to make it hard for a user to accidentally harm a patient by pressing the wrong buttons. The standard disclaimer of liability that is included in most general-purpose software, is *not* acceptable for the regulatory bodies.

Comment: While ignoring that there is some amount of code and physical locks that may be in place to prevent easily making the device harm a patient, I am just trying to separate the fact that having the software open source is different to the device being able to cause harm to a patient.

Comment: You are right that it is not the open-source nature of the software that makes the machine potentially lethal. My point was that, in a regulated industry, you can't shift all the blame to the user, independent of how the software is licensed.

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau Is that actually true? Like there's specific legal precedent for this? or are you just implying that you can't disclaim full liability? Note the specific wording of the GPL: "THERE IS NO WARRANTY FOR THE PROGRAM, **TO THE EXTENT PERMITTED BY APPLICABLE LAW.**"

Comment: @jdwolf the **EXTENT PERMITTED BY APPLICABLE LAW** means the gpl cannot remove legal liability that may be enforced by other laws. If the local law says the manufacturer is responsible for harm to a patient then that cannot be changed. The manufacturer will need to argue whether the fault was in their hardware and software or it was a user of the device and that sufficient safeguards were in place to prevent it. The software being open or closed source, GPL or BSD licensed can't change those legal responsibilities.

Comment: @sambler But the phrasing in the GPL makes that clear. Further if the software author were reasonable for any reason that they couldn't waiver then the clause doesn't matter anyway. What exactly about your claim: _The standard disclaimer of liability that is included in most general-purpose software, is not acceptable for the regulatory bodies._ Applies here?